# Fetch data into tabular format

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to fetch data from database in tabular format. I have taken count variable as a number of rows and 5 columns. When I execute this query all results are fetched in multiple row and single columns.
Here is my code :

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$all_product = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM product WHERE user_id='$fetch_user_id'");
echo '<table style="background-color:white; margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px;">';
$count = mysqli_num_rows($all_product);
$count = ($count / 5) + 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo "<tr[$i]>";

    for ($m = 0; $m < 5; $m++) {
        echo "<td[$m]>";

        while ($all = mysqli_fetch_array($all_product)) {
            echo '<img src="' . $all['image'] . '" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <div class="search_details">
                <figcaption>' . $all['name'] . '</figcaption>
                <figcaption>by ' . $all['brand'] . '</figcaption><figcaption>&#8360;' . $all['price'] . '</figcaption>
                <figcaption>Save: &#8360;' . $local_price . ', (' . $all['discount'] . '%)</figcaption><figcaption>In stock:' . $all['stock'] . '</figcaption></div>';
        }

        echo "</td[$m]>";
    }

    echo "</tr[$i]>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Any help ? Where am I going wrong ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: down vote for the most horribly formatted code i've seen in a while

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: I like the title. Who would have thought of that.

Comment: @e4c5 Is it okay now ??

Comment: People are giving you a hard time for indentation here. That's because most don't have a lot of time to read your question and find problems, but also because having messy code is often a sign of a messy process. Keep things neat, organized, and errors become more obvious. Indent functional sections of code, [there are many examples of how to achieve this](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), and be consistent.

Comment: Probably worse. if indeed that is possible. Why don't you please first take a bit of time to follow @tadman's advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
 <?php
    $all_product = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM product WHERE user_id='$fetch_user_id'");
    $i= 0;
    $m=5;
    echo '<table width="100%" margin-left="30px" style="background-color:white;">';
    while ($all = mysqli_fetch_array($all_product)) {
    if($i%5==0) {
    echo "<tr>";
                }
    echo '<td style="width:20%">';
    echo '<img src="'.$all['image'].'" width="150px" height="150px" />
    <div class="search_details">
    <figcaption>'.$all['name'].'</figcaption>
    <figcaption>by '.$all['brand'].'</figcaption><figcaption>&#8360;'.$all['price'].'</figcaption>
    <figcaption>Save: &#8360;'.$local_price.', ('.$all['discount'].'%)</figcaption><figcaption>In stock: '.$all['stock'] .'</figcaption></div>';
    echo "</td>";
    if($i%$m==$m - 1){
    echo "</tr>";
                 }
    $i++;
                 }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from my answer?

Comment: @Philipp Yea logic is same, what a coincidence but you have redefined the php tags so many times that's not necessary.